# Access 2007 continous form; can it displays data from joined table?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

long time reader, first time posting;

I have a continous form which displays a bunch of fields from table A.

Some fields from Table A are "inner joined" to tables B,C and D on A.x=B.x, A.y=B.y and A.z=C.z .

I'm trying to have my continous form to display the "inner joined" data. For instance, if A.x contains "1" and B.x contains "apple", I want to see "apple" on my form but it only displays "1". I've googled around but can't find any clear answer as to whether this is even possible, and if so how to.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the forms Record Source to refer to an SQL query joining the tables you need instead of referring to Table A. The form will then be able to display any of the columns in this query.

Comment: +1 There may be update difficulties, comboboxes may be an alternative.

Comment: Would the query be updated any time I open the form, or would I have to manually / programmatically "re-run" it any time I open the form?

Comment: The query is automatically run each time you open the form, the same way that a table is re-queried each time the form is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the form and create a query that displays "apple".  Something like this, which imagines "apple" is found in the field called `Description`:

```
SELECT tableA.x, tableB.x, tableB.Description 
FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.x=tableB.x;
```

This is the SQL View.  To apply this, you may need to switch from query Design View.

Once you have "apple" visible in your query result, transferring to the form should be easy.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing some of your tags, `userform` and `vba`.  The solution does not involve `vba` and I think the problem is purely sql.